# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'optimized_write'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I get an

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'optimized_write'
```

error using the following code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(optimized_write=True)
```

I have not been able to find similar issues elsewhere.  It may be related to the fact that I cannot also write large Excel files with openpyxl?

Comment: Using the correct version of the documentation for the version of the library you're using is advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Workbook` class constructor doesn't even have the parameter `optimized_write`, it  accepts only one parameter `write_only`. You can see the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/0f8537998f95c9d8d44913c2edb367516b799d4a/openpyxl/?at=default) and know more.

```
Workbook(write_only = True)
```

this should work

Comment: Yes so it looks like I was working on a wrong implementation of openpyxl.  optimized_write was removed in 2.4.0-a1 (2016-04-11).